# Overwriting Local Git Repo Branches

Tags: git

I'm using:

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

To overwrite my local repo from the remote repo. It allows me to keep my repos updated on two machines (work and home).

I recently created a branch.

I ran the above commands but my branch (`v2`) didn't download.

How do I download every branch from my remote repo to my local repo so it overwrite all local files?

I haven't made any changes to my local files yet, so I can overwrite everything if needed.

Comment: Did you ever push your branch to the remote?

Comment: Would be useful to know the reason behind down votes. Help a brotha out ppl.

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the `v2` branch with the following (via Bitbucket):

`git fetch && git checkout v2`

I had messed up my local `master` branch, so I did what I've been doing:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

I was able to do that since I never made any changes or new commits to my repo at home.

Now both branches on my local repo at home are update from the remote and ready to go.

Although I'm wondering, once I get to work tomorrow, how I overwrite those local repos?

Would it be:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
git fetch && checkout v2
git reset --hard origin/v2
```

Do I have to `fetch` and `reset` each branch individually?

My files seem like the updated ones from the remote repo. Is there anything happening that I may not know about?